# How do you go about solving this recurrence?

Tags: algorithms, recursion, recursive-algorithms

How do you make an estimation for the substitution method, when the recursion tree did not help so much?

I have a recurrence 
$$T(n) = 5\cdot T(n/3) + n (\log n)^2$$
And upon doing the recurrence tree, I got a rather difficult running time

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{\log(n)/\log(3)}  \frac{5^{j-1} n\log_2^2[n/(3^{j-1})]}{(3^{j-1})^2} $$

How do you go about solving this recurrence?

Comment: Forget recurrence trees and the so-called Master's theorem and all that, and simply note that $$5^{-n}T(3^n)=5^{-(n-1)}T(3^{n-1})+3^n5^{-n}n^2(\log3)^2,$$ hence $$5^{-n}T(3^n)=T(1)+\sum_{k=1}^n3^k5^{-k}k^2(\log3)^2.$$ The series whose partial sums are on the RHS converges hence $$T(3^n)\sim5^nC,\qquad C=T(1)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty 3^k5^{-k}k^2(\log3)^2,$$ and my guess is that you were told to deduce from that (although there is no rigorous way to do so...) that $$T(n)=\Theta(n^{\log5/\log3}).$$

Answer (score 1):

There  is another  closely  related recurrence  that  admits an  exact
solution.  Suppose we  have  $T(0)=0$ and  $T(1)=T(2)=1$ and  for
$n\ge 3$
$$T(n) = 5 T(\lfloor n/3 \rfloor) + n \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor^2.$$

It seems reasonable to use integer  values here as the running time of
an algorithm is a function of discrete quantities.

Furthermore let the base three representation of $n$ be
$$n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor} d_k 3^k.$$

Then  we can  unroll the  recurrence to  obtain the  following *exact*
formula for $n\ge 3$
$$T(n) = 5^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor -1} 
5^j \times (\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor - j)^2 \times 
\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor} d_k 3^{k-j}.$$

Now to get  an upper bound consider a string of  value two digits to
obtain
$$T(n) \le 5^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor -1} 
5^j \times (\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor - j)^2 \times 
\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor} 2 \times 3^{k-j}.$$

This simplifies to

$$\frac{1457}{32} 5^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
-\frac{9}{2} \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor^2 3^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
-\frac{45}{2} \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor 3^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
- 45\times 3^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
\\ + \frac{1}{4} \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor^2
+ \frac{5}{8} \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor
+ \frac{15}{32}.$$

This bound is actually attained and cannot be improved upon, just like
the lower bound,  which occurs with a one digit  followed by zeroes to
give

$$T(n) \ge 5^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor -1} 
5^j \times (\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor - j)^2 \times 
3^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor-j}.$$

This simplifies to
$$16\times 5^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
- \frac{3}{2} \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor^2 3^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
- \frac{15}{2} \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor 3^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
- 15 \times 3^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}.$$

Joining the dominant terms of the upper and the lower bound we obtain
the asymptotics
$$5^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
\in \Theta\left(3^{\log_3 5  \times \log_3 n}\right) 
= \Theta\left(n^{\log_3 5}\right).$$

This is in agreement with what the Master theorem would produce.

Comment: How many times did you already posted essentially this answer?

Comment: The text that accompanies the computation may be similar but the constants and the work functions are different every time. I have an archive of these that I check before I reply and I would not post a duplicate. I have noticed that you have also replied to these on several occasions and you will have seen me post links instead of answers when duplicates appear.

Comment: @Did I honestly do not understand the downvote. There are many users at MSE who have made a specialty of a certain topic and repeatedly answer closely related questions with considerable overlap, e.g. prestigious people who do contour integration, integer relation algorithms or combinatorics especially inclusion-exclusion. With me it is the same and master theorem recurrences count among my favorites. I do not see the flaw in this answer except perhaps that I used a CAS, not illegal either. I have some posts on this topic that give rise to some simple but  very pretty generating functions.

Comment: 1. How do you know who votes what? 2. How do you define "prestigious people" on mse? 3. (Main question:) Is the very specialized algorithm you devised, the first and only thing to explain and to systematically push to the forefront when answering these questions? This takes the risk that uninformed readers take it for the main result of the field while it is at best anecdotal...

Comment: Prestiguous here means having high reputation. Let me point out that I never fail to refer to the master theorem or Akra-Bazzi in my posts which should direct inquiry to these powerful methods. Presumably many of these posters are working with a textbook where the best methods are explained. The algorithm, which is folklore, just unrolls the recursion tree which is apparently standard with these problems and I certainly make no claim to originality. I think it may be useful when people run into computational trouble with the standard procedure, which it is not designed to replace but augment.

Comment: Except that these menial computational problems are, most of the time, exactly the trouble the OP is having, hence posts focusing only on your cherished exact method actually *do not answer the question as asked*.

Comment: MSE says to close this discussion. I think I see your point. What exactly constitutes a match to the poster's intent is somewhat subjective however. If you radically promote pedagogical considerations that would eliminate the element of competitiveness and fun from MSE. I can certainly say that I have learned mathematical ideas at this site that never would have appeared here if it were purely pedagogical.